# Just take a breath

Tags: riddle

> I'll make you stop and take a breath,
>   and you'll continue, or else comes death.
>   I'm smart - my brother went to college
>   across the seas to gain some knowledge.
>
> Some people don't like me nearly enough -
>   it makes understanding them I think too tough.
>   But one thing's for certain and, man, this is true -
>   I'd rather see too many me's than too few.

**Who or what am I?**

Hint:

> You've seen me today if you read this riddle

Comment: Great riddle! I'm guessing this is a "who am I" puzzle? You could perhaps do with making that clear, at the moment there is a rhyme but no question.

Comment: "I'm smart! My brother went to college!" :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve come to realize

> you are a **comma**.

I'll make you stop and take a breath, / and you'll continue, or else comes death.

> Commas allow one to take a brief pause when reading. I think the second line references either literal death (if the reader doesn’t exhale) or the death of the idea conveyed by the sentence read.

I'm smart - my brother went to college / across the seas to gain some knowledge.

> A reference to the [Oxford comma](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-oxford-comma/). Named after the Oxford University Press, it is an optional comma that precedes “and” within a list (though, if you ask me, it ain’t optional). :-)

Some people don't like me nearly enough - /
it makes understanding them I think too tough.

> Commas may be seen as unnecessary clutter. However, a lack of commas can cause confusion, as (maybe?) exemplified here.

But one thing's for certain and, man, this is true -
I'd rather see too many me's than too few.

> I agree; I prefer commas for the sake of clarity. A sentence’s meaning can change if it’s missing a sorely needed comma. See [here](https://www.verbicidemagazine.com/2011/09/20/strippers-jfk-and-stalin-illustrate-why-you-should-use-the-serial-comma/) for a fun joke.

Comment: +1 for the joke :-D

Comment: +1 for the joke, and you are correct. The line with "It makes understanding them I think too tough" was indeed meant to rot13(fbhaq jrveq jvgubhg pbzznf).